# How Can Solve a "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child." error in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am trying to create a blog using react, while working on the Navigation using react Routes, I encountered this error "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it." I have tried so much solutions but none worked, including the solutions for similar problems on here. Please, does anyone have an idea of what i can do to fix this?

I have updated React Router to the latest version, i have also called the component as a function but to no avail.

Below is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import PageRenderer from './page-render';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/:page" element={PageRenderer} />
          <Route path="/" render={() => <Navigate to="/home" />} />
          <Route element={() => 404} />
        </Routes>

      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;type here
```

Below is my render-page.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

const generatePage = page => {
    const component = () => require(`./pages/${page}.js`).default

    try {
        return React.createElement(component());
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
        return React.createElement(() => 404)
    }
}

const PageRenderer = () => {
    const {
        params: { page }
    } = useMatch()

    return generatePage(page)
}

export default PageRenderer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
after seeing the repository, some adjustments are still needed.
First of all let's look at the app.js again
we have to adjust the part of the pagerenderer

```js
<Route path="/:page" element={<PageRenderer />} />
```

in your current code, you only pass the function, which ultimately causes the error. We need to pass the pagerenderer as a component.

this causes consequential errors.

If we look at the page renderer, in addition to the already mentioned adjustments regarding the synchronization of the loading of the external files, the parameter selection must also be adjusted.

Both useParams() and useMatch() are hooks used in React Router to work with route parameters. However, there are differences in their uses and functionalities.

useParams(): This hook allows you to read parameters from the current route. For example, if your route is defined /user/:id and the current path is /user/123, then useParams() returns { id: '123' }.

the adjusted code looks like this

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const generatePage = async page => {
    let component;

    try {
        component = await import(`./pages/${page}.js`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return () => 404;
    }

    return component.default || component;
};

const PageRenderer = () => {


    const { page } = useParams();

    const [Component, setComponent] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {
        generatePage(page).then((comp) => {
            setComponent(() => comp);
        });
    }, [page]);

    return Component ? <Component /> : null;
};

export default PageRenderer;
```

so you should not get any more errors

**OLD ANSWER**
In your current setup, you're trying to require a page module and instantly creating a React element from it in your generatePage function, but that might not always work as expected due to the nature of JavaScript modules.

You have to adjust the generatePage function to make sure, to handle a async import

```js
const generatePage = async page => {
    let component;

    try {
        component = await import(`./pages/${page}.js`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return () => 404;
    }

    return component.default || component;
};
```

and adjust the PageRenderer to set the state sync via the [useEffect](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook

```js
const PageRenderer = () => {
    const {
        params: { page }
    } = useMatch();

    const [Component, setComponent] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        generatePage(page).then((comp) => {
            setComponent(() => comp);
        });
    }, [page]);

    return Component ? <Component /> : null;
};

export default PageRenderer;
```

but the main problem is probably in your 404 page.

You pass a function to the route that you neither call nor define as a component

You should create a own component for this and pass that

```js
<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> // NotFound is a component you define that renders a 404 page.
```

Comment: I have innitiated all the changes you gave and created a separate Not found page, but i still got same error. If you don't mind, can I share the github link with you so you could help look at it in your spare time? Thank you

Comment: this or reproduce the error with a jsfiddle / codesandbox and i will take a look

Comment: This is the link to the github repo. 
  https://github.com/Sunnybrown/my-tech-blog.git

Comment: @SundayBrownAkobo i have looked at your code and corrected errors. You can find the procedure in my edit answer

Comment: Thank you so much. The updated code solved the error, the code is now working fine